# make a loop with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the python script i'm working with. The problem is, when i press a (plus)button it need to multiply the display number. For example, you pressed the button ones it displays 0.05mm, when the button is pressed again it need to say 0.1mm etc. This is with steps of 0.05mm per press. I have looked for some examples but i can't compare it with my problem.

What i already have is this:

```
sum = 0
 i = 0
 while i<10:
     sum = sum + i - sum
     print (sum)
     i = i + 0.05
```

It has no pauze or something like that, When 10 is passed it stops.

Have someone any solution of my problem?

Comment: I'd say start creating a button, and an event loop, following tkinter docs. Without listening to an event, yes, the result will be sequential.

Comment: You should probably change the name of `sum` to something else since `sum` is a built-in method used for summing lists and the like; e.g. `sum([1,2,3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of the question, you only want to increment the sum by 0.05 each time you press the button (If I misunderstood, all you have to change is the operation inside the function). Just make the button  call the function

```
value = 0

def increment():
    global value
    value += 0.05
    print value
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this:

```
def vermedigvuldiging1():
    global value1
    value1 += 0.05
    print (value1)
    display1["text"] = (round(value1,2))

def vermedigvuldiging2():
    global value2
    value2 += 0.05
    print (value2)
    display2["text"] = (round(value2,2))

def vermedigvuldiging3():
    global value3
    value3 += 0.05
    print (value3)
    display3["text"] = (round(value3,2))

def vermindering1():
    global value1
    value1 -= 0.05
    print (value1)
    display1["text"] = (round(value1,2))

def vermindering2():
    global value2
    value2 -= 0.05
    print (value2)
    display2["text"] = (round(value2,2))

def vermindering3():
    global value3
    value3 -= 0.05
    print (value3)
    display3["text"] = (round(value3,2))
```

The label:

```
display1 = Label(root, font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
display1.place(x=250, y=240)

display2 = Label(root, font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
display2.place(x=600, y=240)

display3 = Label(root, font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
display3.place(x=600, y=10)
```

It has worked for me, but not the best program ;)
thanks for the tips!

Comment: It could probably be simplified a lot, if you wanted to. `value1`, `value2`, ... and the display variables could be contained in a dictionary. Your `vermedigvuldiging2` and `vermindering2` functions could be a single function (no repetitions) that decrements or increments values in the dictionary and updates the labels accordingly.